# How can I do conditional monadic parsing using parsec?

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

Imagine the following example

```
data A = ...
data B = ...
data C = ...

convertA :: A -> C

parseA :: Parser A
parseB :: Parser B

parseC :: Parser C
parseC = do
  a <- parseA
  if parsed? a
    then return $ convertA a
    else parseB
```

Is there a way to implement such logic where I can try to use a parser, and if it is successful do some transformation on the result, and otherwise use another parser? I know this particular example could be written such as the following

```
parseC = (convertA <$> parseA) <|> parseB
```

but is there a more general way to represent this pattern in the monadic notation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can represent it more monadically, but I don't know if I'd call it a more general pattern.

Normally, success or failure of a parser is handled implicitly through the `MonadPlus` and `Alternative` interfaces. However, you can reify success/failure and operate on it in the `Monad` context if you really want to. The function to do that reification is `optionMaybe` in [Text.Parsec.Combinator](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.5/docs/Text-Parsec-Combinator.html).

```
parseC :: Parser C
parseC = do
    ma <- optionMaybe parseA
    case ma of
        Just a -> return $ convertA a
        Nothing -> parseB
```

One important note here is that `optionMaybe` is..  special. It only succeeds with a `Nothing` result in the case when the parser provided to it fails *without consuming input*.  Of course your example code is broken *anyway* if `parseA` can consume input while failing, so I assume you're familiar with that issue. This brokenness is why I hate parsec and will never use it in my own code, by the way. Sorry for the editorializing, I just don't think that issue is something every user should be forced to stumble over.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would you expect a non-broken parser to do? Implicitly `try` everything?

Comment: Thanks for explaining this, in the end I just ended up doing `try (convertA <$> parseA) <|> parseB`. Would `try` work together with `optionMaybe`? Also, what do you use instead of parsec? :)

Comment: @JakubArnold Yeah, `try` works fine with `optionMaybe`.
@thatotherguy For truly composable parsers, I like what you get out of `uu-parsinglib`, which is a lot like having an implicit `try` everywhere, though it's a bit smarter than that. For efficient parsers, I'd just use `attoparsec`. It has similar issues to the ones `parsec` has, but at least it is explicitly about performance all the way.